# How to correctly write .htaccess for maintenance mode?

Tags: .htaccess, maintenance-mode

I know the basics for writing an .htaccess that handle a maintenance mode page.

I don't want to use a plugin, as I need to replace the whole WP site while in maintenance mode.

I've tried to add additional rules to allows access to WP Back-End, only for specific IPs.

I've tried several attempts and eventually got very close to what I need.

However, I also want the white-listed IP(s) be able to see the front-end site, without being redirected to the maintenance page, but I'm stuck there.

Here's my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin/.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/.* [OR]
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^93\.62\.93\.79
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance-mode\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance-mode.html [R=302,L]
```

What I'm supposed to add/change?

Answer (score 0):

Did you found a solution? I don't tested it with WP but this worked for me for another CMS.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# exclude file (otherwise infinity loop)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/under-construction/maintenance\.php$
# exclude images and css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css) [NC]
# If it's not your IP address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111\.222\.333\.444$
# Redirect /abc to example.com/abc.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/under-construction/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: Not really. I've ended up using an index.html and renaming it when I should leave the maintenance mode. Not an elegant way, but I was in hurry. Thank you for your help anyway!